# Cyclic subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[image]

I think that this statement is true if $V$ is finite dimensional. If $V$ is infinite dimensional and it's basis be $\{\alpha_i\}$ $\forall i\in N$ and linear transformation $T(\alpha_i)=\alpha_{i+1}$. Then $<\alpha_1>$ is a cyclic invariant subspace and infinite dimensional.
Am I thinking right?

Comment: Why is $\langle a_1\rangle$ infinite dimensional?

Comment: $T^i(\alpha_1)=\alpha_{i+1}$ and hence $\{T^i(\alpha_1)\}$ set is linearly independent.

Comment: Maybe you have a different definition of the terminology, but for mine, "cyclic" implies "invariant", so "cyclic invariant" is redundant. But yes, there is an implicit assumption of finite-dimensionality in that statement. Probably, it is stated somewhere earlier in the text that they are working in finite-dimensions only, and therefore do not feel the need to point this out every time.